My blazor..js and blazor..css files are being regenerated when publishing and it's throwing an error
I'm trying to deploy a project that I recently updated from .net 5 to .net 8 and the publish command is erroring out with the error:

error MSB3030: Could not copy the file"wwwroot\blazor.{random_guid}.js" because it was not found.

Every time I try to publish, these files (blazor.{random_guid}.js and blazor.{random_guid}.css are regenerated with a new guid.  The .csproj file still has a hard reference to the previous files:

<Content Update="wwwroot\blazor.{random_guid}.css">
<Content Update="wwwroot\blazor.{random_guid}.js">

While index.html in the same wwwroot directory is updated to point to the newly generated files:

<script defer src="blazor.{new_guid}.js"></script><link href ="blazor.{new_guid}.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

How do I go about either preventing these files from being regenerated or allowing the code to reference the newly generated files?

CSS isolation bundling should be handling that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#css-isolation-bundling
